# Facebook login with multiple apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 2 mobile apps. These apps have different names and branding. However, as both these companies are partners, we have the same login system. This means the user should be able to use the same login details for both apps.

I want to add Facebook login to both of these apps.

**Solution 1: Use same FB App ID**

The easiest option is to use the same registered Facebook App for both applications.

The issue here is that I need a different logo & app name to appear when logging in with Facebook. However, the FB dashboard only allows you to specify one app name & logo for each app.

**Solution 2: Create another app in FB Dashboard**

Another solution is to create another app in FB developer portal, and use 2 different FB ids. The issue here is that if a user logs into both apps, it is not clear that they are using the same account. Before we had a `fb_id` attribute, but it looks like we cannot use this anymore. Also, a user can revoke certain permissions on one app, and not the other, causing things to be out of sync.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: 1: Not really possible. 2: If you have both apps registered to the same business, you can use the `ids_for_business` field to identify users across apps. For the “out of sync” issue on permissions, you would have to implement a check which permissions were granted, and re-prompt for missing ones.